# Colorbox Inline Form Redirect

Tags: html, forms, redirect, colorbox, inline

I  have a very simple Inline Colorbox on my site to display contact form.

I've gotten the form to look good and submit, no problem... but for the life of me, I cannot get it to Redirect to another Colorbox once the form is submitted.

As is shown in the Colorbox examples, I can move via a link to the Ajax "Homer" window, but I can't figure out how to make an action like that happen as part of my simple HTML redirect.

Here's my HTML redirect code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.ZZZ.com/ZZZ/submitted.html">
```

I know... very basic, and I'm using formmail.pl. So really nothing fancy.

I just want the Colorbox to display a "Your information has been submitted" page, and then let the user click outside the box to return to the main page. Is there a way to accomplish this, or should I not have used the "Inline" function to begin with?

Comment: Are you sumbitting your form with Ajax?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a java submit. Here's the code:

    <a class="buttonBOX submit" href="javascript: return null" onClick="document.getElementById('form-main').submit()">Send Message</a>

The button itself is a colored box with centered text, and a CSS color change when hovering.